# Add css to nodes of certain content type

Tags: 8, theming

I've been trying to add css to a content type for a while, but I can't seem to find any help on this for drupal 8.

How do you add a library to only the nodes of a content type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generic answer:

```
if (some condition) {
  $something['#attached']['library'][] = 'yourmodule/yourlibrary';
}
```

If you're in a module, do it in `hook_node_view()` and add it to $build. If you're in a theme, do it in `hook_preprocess_node()` and add it to $variables.

some_condition for your case would be `$node->getType() == 'your_type'`, in case of preprocess, the node object is in `$variables['node']`

You can even do it directly within a template with `attach_library()`, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2456753.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir. I sorry I didn't mention it earlier, but I am doing this for theme and preprocess_page(&$variables). However, I still can't get it to work. I ended up with something like this: `function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $node == $variables['node'];
  if ($node->getType() == 'CONTENT-TYPE') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'THEME/LIBRARY';
  }
}` This results in "Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object"

Comment: You're doing it in preprocess_page(). As I said, you should do it in preprocess_node(). You have a fatal because not all pages have a node. But preprocess_node() is only called if you actually have a node. So either check that you have a node object or move it to the correct preprocess. Note that you might want to check the view mode as well, depending on whether it should only be added to full, teaser or whatever...

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing someting, but `function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'CONTENT_TYPE') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'THEME/LIBRARY';
  }
}` still returns the same fatal error.

Comment: You are missing something yes, you're not defining $node anymore.

Comment: With or without it, it doesn't work. Rephrased: `function crimesto_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node == $variables['node'];
  if ($node->getType() == 'wanted') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'crimesto/wanted_print';
  }
}` doesn't work...

Comment: Oh, that's why. Although `$node == $variables['node']` doesn't work, `$node = $variables['node']` does. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `==` is a comparison operator, `=` is an assignment operator.